# Understanding usage of quantile function (norm.ppf), passing p vs 1-p

Tags: normal-distribution, quantiles, scipy

I was given a question related to the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) using `scipy.stats.norm.ppf`, along with its solution  - which I don't understand.

I'm changing the question details, but citing the exact final wording:

A painter's annual sales of paintings have a normal distribution of $N(30, 8)$.

Next year, the painter wants to take a sabbatical and not paint at all, but still wants a reasonable annual income.
So the painter decides to work hard in the coming months, and prepare an inventory of paintings to sell them next year.

Now, the question:

> [The painter] wants the chance of selling all paintings next year to be 70%. How many paintings should be prepared?

The solution is `norm.ppf(0.3)`, while I thought it should be `norm.ppf(0.7)`.

Can you help me understand why `0.3` is correct here, and in what case using `0.7` would be correct?

Comment: Presumably "sales" are *counts* of paintings -- but then adopting a Normal distribution makes little sense.  I guess we are supposed to overlook that and understand this to approximate the distribution.   Regardless, neither of the options you provide is correct, because neither uses any information about this distribution (mean of 30, sd of 8 -- or maybe the square root of 8?).  *Either* of these values could be used in creating a solution because they are negatives of each other.

Comment: @whuber, I guess I could have omitted the mean and the sd (indeed sd) values from the question and it would still hold. The original solution does use those values, running `distr = st.norm(mu, sigma)` and then `distr.ppf(1-0.7)`. if those *specific* values don't make sense - it's on me, as I changed them, as mentioned. Knowing that, is it answerable?

Comment: Consider the definition: the percentage point function with an argument of $p$ returns a quantity that has only a $p$ chance of *exceeding* the random variable.  (You can confirm that `scipy` uses this definition by printing out some values.)  So, which argument -- 0.3 or 0.7 -- corresponds to the question?

Comment: @whuber, I know that'd sound stupid, but well, 0.71 exceeds 0.7, and so 0.8, 0.9, etc. 0.3 certainly doesn't. hence I went for `ppf(0.7)`.